# Reclaim User History Android

Tags: android

How to check if the app is a fresh installation or a re installation. I want the user to have his history downloaded if its a re-installation like whats app. I thought of writing the user id in the shared preference but that is not possible as the data may get erased once the app is uninstalled. I am already having a folder of my app on the device which is used for image caching and downloading new images, but this is not reliable as the user may delete the folder. What else can I try ???

Comment: I'd suggest you integrate with Google Play Services. People switch phone every two years. Some have more than one device. And some share their device with their kids. Linking a user history to a particular google account is the ideal way to go.

Comment: Thanx for that i didnt knew about it. could you link me up to some good simple tutorial and plus what i can do if i want the same for facebook users on my app.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain the user storage with getExternStorage, then leave a file there that specifies the usage history. The file you save there will survive uninstalls and reinstalls. Of course the user can delete that file but generally they will not, and if you name it properly they will realize it is part of a program.

Comment: I am already doing that but i need it to be user specific and plus it has a loop hole of user deleting the folder.Is there anything else i can try apart from that.

Comment: You didn't mention that you already tried getExternalStorage (that is not the same as the shared preferences). Nor did you mention that you were interested in app installation history across multiple devices. In that case you might need identity management, your own server and then you can track whatever you want.

Comment: ok the question is updated. Can you link me up to some tutorials for identity management on the server that would be great.

Comment: I personally hate it when apps store information outside their default folders. Play Services is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you integrate with Android's Backup Service.

People switch phone every two years. Some factory reset their device. Some have more than one device. And some share their device with their kids. Linking a user history so that it follows a particular google account is the [ideal way to go.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)

As to your question regarding Facebook integration, I'm afraid I know too little about that topic to be of any help.

Comment: k thanx for the help 
let me try it

Comment: Hey this is for the game stuff like the leaderboard and the snapshots etc. How can i use it for my advantage in a simple app like WHATS APP

Comment: Sorry, you should use this then. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html